# Triggering a State Change Between Sibling Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Total React noob here. I have two sibling Components in my React application. I want to display a Loading message in `Component A` when a certain method is executed in `Component B`

I'm familiar with passing state from a parent to child in React, but how can a sibling be notified to display it's loader?

Here's what I have so far

```
export default class ComponentA extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render(){
    return(
      {/* Loader */}
      { this.state.loading === true &&
        <div className="loader"></div>
      }
    )
  }
}

export default class ComponentB extends Component {  
  // Constructor, bindings and stuff...

  getData(){  
    // Update Component A's "loading" state here.
    // Once the data is fetched, set "loading" to false
  }
  render(){
    return(
       <div>
         <button onClick="this.getData"></button>
         <table>
           <tbody>
             {/* ... */}
           </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Setting up both Components to inherit state from a Parent Component doesn't seem desirable because I'll have many siblings with nested Components that I'll also want to trigger this loader

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: 2 options, create a parent component (aka container component) that passes messages between the 2 sibling components.. or, move state to redux store and connect both siblings to redux store

Comment: Either you use some form of global state, or you make the components inherit from the parent.

Comment: @Varinder I think I'll dive into redux to control this. Parent 2 Children could get a bit messy

Answer (score 3):

In React, data flows from the top, down. You'd need to wrap Component A and B in a parent and [keep the state in the parent](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) as a single point of truth.

However, as you have said after a while this can become tedious when dealing with components several levels deep. You don't want to have to keep passing the state down.

I'd suggest looking into [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) (the docs are excellent) as well as the [container(smart)/component(dumb) architecture](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

In addition to the links above, I'd really suggest taking the time to watch this [free tutorial series](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux) from Redux's creator, Dan Abramov.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you said that Component A is a child component of Component B but I don't see any relationship between the two components. But you can do one of 2 things in my opinion. One is to import Component A into Component B as a child component and pass the data to Component A as props (easy). Second way requires you to understand redux. In this case, I don't see the necessity due to the size of the app. However, basically you can have a mastermind at the top of the React component tree to pass down the state to any component. So updating the store by dispatching the new data from Component B will enable Component A to have an access to the data. Redux would be great from large applications and for data that needs to be distributed in multiple places.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but I did not say A was a Child of B. I am currently looking into Redux as this app will scale

Comment: I'm so sorry! Sibling and child got me so confused. But redux is the best way to go in that case. Good luck!